# Use Devenv.com to show output in commandline and an Output Log file

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, jenkins, devenv

How can I use the devenv.com to show the output in command line window as well as an external log file. I am using the following command line for building a solution file:

```
devenv.com  /Build "Release|Win32" SolutionFile.sln >> D:\SolutionLog.log
```

Using the above command line the output is written only to the `SolutionLog.log` file and not to the command line. How can I modify the above command to get the command in command line as well as to an external log file.

Answer (score 6):

Try the /out parameter:

```
devenv.com  /Build "Release|Win32" SolutionFile.sln /out D:\SolutionLog.log
```